# Flattening a list in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, flatten

I'm attempting to create a function for flattening lists in the R5RS language in scheme and am experiencing the issue where my function simply returns the input list without removing the parenthesis. I figured this was due to the extra cons, but when I remove it the output becomes the list without the elements that were in the parenthesis. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
(define (denestify lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)'())
        ((list? (car lst))(cons (denestify (cons (car (car lst))(cdr (car lst))))
                                (denestify (cdr lst))))
        (else (cons (car lst)(denestify (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tags=flatten%20scheme&mode=all&pageSize=50

Comment: @coredump I'm getting a broken link

Comment: it's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flatten%2bscheme?tab=Active

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to *flatten* a list of lists, then you have to use `append` to combine each sublist. Besides, your implementation is overly complicated, try this instead:

```
(define (denestify lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((pair? (car lst))
         (append (denestify (car lst))
                 (denestify (cdr lst))))
        (else (cons (car lst) (denestify (cdr lst))))))
```

For example:

```
(denestify '(1 (2 (3 4 (5) (6 (7) (8)) (9))) 10))
=> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Answer (score 7):

This shows how to convert Óscar López answer into one that doesn't use `append` and is also tail recursive:

```
(define (denestify-helper lst acc stk)
  (cond ((null? lst) 
         (if (null? stk) (reverse acc)
             (denestify-helper (car stk) acc (cdr stk))))
        ((pair? (car lst))
         (denestify-helper (car lst) acc (cons (cdr lst) stk)))
        (else 
         (denestify-helper (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc) stk))))

(define (denestify lst) (denestify-helper lst '() '()))

(denestify '(1 (2 (3 4 (5) (6 (7) (8)) (9))) 10))
```

Note how it uses the accumulator to build up the list in reverse and also a list as a stack.

Which results in

```
'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

as expected.

---

After I posted this I thought of this change:

```
(define (denestify-helper lst acc stk)
  (cond ((null? lst) 
         (if (null? stk) (reverse acc)
             (denestify-helper (car stk) acc (cdr stk))))
        ((pair? (car lst))
         (denestify-helper (car lst) acc (if (null? (cdr lst)) 
                                             stk 
                                             (cons (cdr lst) stk))))
        (else 
         (denestify-helper (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc) stk))))
```

Which eliminates some useless `cons`ing by effectively doing tail-call optimization on our stack. One could go further and optimize handling of one element lists.